# "Could not fetch URL" using IMPORTHTML

Tags: google-sheets

I get "Could not fetch URL" as soon as I open my google sheets. The weird thing is once I open the sheets these functions would not work, but if type them again in a cell it will work and scrape the website. What is up with that? I'm only importing a few tables, so my sheets are not overloaded with data. Example of my formula is below.

```
=IMPORTHTML("https://stockanalysis.com/stocks/"&Fundamentals!B3&"/financials","table")
```

UPDATE:
**Problem was solved without any modifications

Comment: Is it happening all the time? How many imports do you have?

Comment: Yes it is happening all the time. I do about 6 imports.

Comment: Can you share a copy of your sheet? I have tried it with many more IMPORTHTML than 6 and they are all returning the data without issue.

Comment: @Kessy Hey Kessy, it is now working I think it had something to do with the website but thanks!

Comment: Hi glad it was fixed, can you set the issue and the end result in an answer so other people can see it was solved without modifications more easily?

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax error in your formula, try this:

```
=IMPORTHTML("https://stockanalysis.com/stocks/"&Fundamentals!B3&"/financials/";"table";1)
```

Comment: Although my old formula works when I enter into a new cell, I will try this.