# importHTML (Google Sheets) formula stopped working

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, google-sheets-formula

I used the following formula for almost a year now and suddenly it stopped working and is not importing the table.

`=IMPORTHTML("https://tradingeconomics.com/matrix";"table";1)`

It gives me a *"Could not fetch url: https://tradingeconomics.com/matrix* error. I also tried the importXML function - same problem.

I tried https://www.octoparse.com just to see if it was able to scrape the data. And it is able to scrape and parse out the data and export it to various formats (you need to install a program for it), although it doesn't solve the problem of automatically importing into Sheet via formula.

**Any ideas about what the problem could be and how I need to adapt the formula**?

Note: I can't code, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

There have being several posts here and other places about the same error message realted to IMPORTHTML. Here are some previous questions bout the same error message that were fixed without making any change:

- [Google spreadsheet importHTML Could not fetch URL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25283037/1595451)
- ["Could not fetch URL" using IMPORTHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70949817/1595451)

Sometimes the problem is caused by something on the Google side and there isn't any change that can be done on the formula to fix it, the only thing to do is to report the problem to Google from the help menu and wait. At this time the option is shown to me as "Help Sheets improve" but this might change without any notice as it has being done several times.

You might also report it through the official Google Editors Help forum.

Related

- [How to know if Google Sheets IMPORTDATA, IMPORTFEED, IMPORTHTML or IMPORTXML functions are able to get data from a resource hosted on a website?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/115664/88163)

Answer (score 0):

try cached version:

```
https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:ZNJKOXQm2t4J:https://tradingeconomics.com/matrix+&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk
```

---

```
=IMPORTHTML("https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:https://tradingeconomics.com/matrix", "table", 1)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's actually a genius idea. Never thought of trying the cached version. Although I still don't know what the issue is. And depending on how old the cached version is it could result in much older data. Any idea how to narrow down what the problem could be?

Comment: @VforVendetta not sure either how it holds. this is 1st time I tried it so we would need to test it against time.

Comment: @VforVendetta if you use it like: `https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:https://tradingeconomics.com/matrix` my guess is that you will get always up to date cached version